# pandas groupby - wrong number of dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with information about temperature, something like this:

```
DateTime,Temperature
2014-11-12-12:43:12,24
2014-12-12-13:45:12,10
2014-12-12-13:46:12,20
2014-12-13-05:47:13,24
2014-12-13-05:48:13,20
2014-12-13-06:49:13,24
```

I would like to use pandas to average the temperature and group by hour, day, month and save the results in another file. Something like this:

```
Month,Day,Hour,AverageTemperature
11,12,12,24
12,12,13,15
12,13,05,22
12,13,06,22
```

I tried this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("datatemp.dat", parse_dates='DateTime', index_col=0, sep=",")
month_day_hour_means = df.groupby(lambda x: (x.hour, x.month)).mean()
print df
```

and unfortunately I got this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code works fine in Pandas version 0.15.1.

```
In [74]: df.groupby(lambda x: (x.hour, x.month)).mean()
Out[74]: 
          Temperature
(5, 12)            22
(6, 12)            24
(12, 11)           24
(13, 12)           15
```

However, you could instead use the following which, as an added bonus, is quicker:

```
In [73]: df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.month]).mean()
Out[73]: 
       Temperature
5  12           22
6  12           24
12 11           24
13 12           15
```

The lambda function is called once for each item in `df.index`. 
In contrast, `df.index.hour` and `df.index.month` generate the desired values
using a fast Cythonized function.

---

```
result = df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.day, df.index.month]).mean().reset_index()
result.columns = ['Hour', 'Day', 'Month', 'AverageTemperature']

result[['Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'AverageTemperature']]
```

yields

```
   Month  Day  Hour  AverageTemperature
0     12   13     5                  22
1     12   13     6                  24
2     11   12    12                  24
3     12   12    13                  15
```

Comment: df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.month]).mean() works fine. Thanks a lot